# Why is my sidebar getting pushed underneath the main page content? (Again)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Two days ago, I asked why some content that was separated into columns was getting pushed underneath another column, [and received a very helpful answer from @Josie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62247339/how-to-make-a-partially-un-editable-table-cell-compatible-with-inline-javascript). This did the trick until I made a table, and for some reason it broke the display order.

Some background: By creating unequal columns with CSS, I've attempted to divide up the page into a large column with main content (`.leftcolumn`) and slimmer column (`.rightcolumn`) that serves as a sidebar. However, the sidebar is getting pushed underneath the main content unless I make the width of either column 2% less than what it is.

I tried switching the order of the tags [as recommended by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62247339/how-to-make-a-partially-un-editable-table-cell-compatible-with-inline-javascript), but this had no effect. I also tried to give a `display: flex` property to the main content [as suggested by answers here][2], but this only combined the two sample posts in the main content along one row while having no effect on the sidebar. Something else I tested was to assign `position: relative` to the main content and `position: absolute` to the sidebar, which was [the solution given by this answer][3], but this had no effect on the actual display. I also tried @rajneesh-tiwari's suggestion below to define `z-index: 999` under the sidebar's parent container, but this, too, had no effect on the display.

Below is the code. For some reason, the sidebar breaks into the bottom of the table...

```html
<head>
  <style>
    * {
      color: black;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    body {
      background: gray;
      padding: 5px;
    }

    .header {
      background-color: white;
      border-radius: 4px;
      padding: 25px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .header h1 {
      font-size: 50px;
    }

    .header p {
      font-size: 15px;
      font-style: italic;
    }

    .topnav {
      background-color: #444;
      border-radius: 4px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .topnav a {
      color: white;
      float: left;
      max-width: 25%;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .topnav a:hover {
      background-color: #eee;
      color: black;
    }

    .topnav a:active {
      background-color: #444;
      color: white;
    }

    .leftcolumn {
      float: left;
      width: 75%;
    }

    .rightcolumn {
      background-color: white;
      float: left;
      padding-left: 20px;
      width: calc(25% - 20px);
    }

    .card {
      background-color: white;
      border-radius: 4px;
      margin-top: 20px;
      padding: 20px;
    }

    .row:after {
      clear: both;
      content: "";
      display: table;
    }

    table {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      margin: 5px;
      width: 100%;
    }

    th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      margin: 5px;
      padding: 5px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
      .leftcolumn, .rightcolumn {
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
      .topnav a {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Weight Calculator</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="topnav">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="calculator.html">Calculator</a>
    <a href="solutions.html">Solutions</a>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="leftcolumn">
      <div class="card">
        <table>
          <caption>Weight Calculator</caption>
          <tr>
            <th>Person</th>
            <th>Weight</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jack</td>
            <td id="jack" oninput="myFunction()">1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td id="john" oninput="myFunction()">2</td>
          </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Joe</td>
            <td id="joe" oninput="myFunction()">3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td id="total"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          document.getElementById("jack").contentEditable = true;
          document.getElementById("john").contentEditable = true;
          document.getElementById("joe").contentEditable = true;

          function myFunction()  {
            var jack2 = document.getElementById("jack").innerText;
            var john2 = document.getElementById("john").innerText;
            var joe2 = document.getElementById("joe").innerText;

            var total2 = parseInt(jack2) + parseInt(john2) + parseInt (joe2);

            document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total2;
          }

            myFunction();
        </script>

    <div class="rightcolumn">
      <div class="card">
        <h3>Test</h3>
        <p>Text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h3>Test</h3>
        <p>Text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h3>Test</h3>
        <p>Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why is the 'rightcolumn' div outside the row ? Shouldn't it be the child of the div with class 'row' ?

Comment: Hahaha, I'm so stupid. This fixed it! If you want to answer the question I can mark this as answered and give you the points. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give the 2 child divs the ( leftcolumn and rightcolumn ) in a common parent (row ). That should solve the issue here.

PS - This is nothing to do with issue. Doing the above should solve your present issue. But the ideal way for arranging items side by side would be to use flexbox. You could give to row. No need to use float- left to both the childs , this would be more of an ideal way to achieve this type of layout

```
.row {
   display: flex
}
```

A far better solution would be using bootstrap, you can easily achieve this type of layouts using boostrap grid system - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

```html
<head>
  <style>
    * {
      color: black;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    body {
      background: gray;
      padding: 5px;
    }

    .header {
      background-color: white;
      border-radius: 4px;
      padding: 25px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .header h1 {
      font-size: 50px;
    }

    .header p {
      font-size: 15px;
      font-style: italic;
    }

    .topnav {
      background-color: #444;
      border-radius: 4px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .topnav a {
      color: white;
      float: left;
      max-width: 25%;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .topnav a:hover {
      background-color: #eee;
      color: black;
    }

    .topnav a:active {
      background-color: #444;
      color: white;
    }

    .leftcolumn {
      float: left;
      width: 75%;
    }

    .rightcolumn {
      background-color: white;
      float: left;
      padding-left: 20px;
      width: calc(25% - 20px);
    }

    .card {
      background-color: white;
      border-radius: 4px;
      margin-top: 20px;
      padding: 20px;
    }

    .row:after {
      clear: both;
      content: "";
      display: table;
    }

    table {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      margin: 5px;
      width: 100%;
    }

    th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      margin: 5px;
      padding: 5px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
      .leftcolumn, .rightcolumn {
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
      .topnav a {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Weight Calculator</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="topnav">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="calculator.html">Calculator</a>
    <a href="solutions.html">Solutions</a>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="leftcolumn">
      <div class="card">
        <table>
          <caption>Weight Calculator</caption>
          <tr>
            <th>Person</th>
            <th>Weight</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jack</td>
            <td id="jack" oninput="myFunction()">1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td id="john" oninput="myFunction()">2</td>
          </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Joe</td>
            <td id="joe" oninput="myFunction()">3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td id="total"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightcolumn">
      <div class="card">
        <h3>Test</h3>
        <p>Text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h3>Test</h3>
        <p>Text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h3>Test</h3>
        <p>Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          document.getElementById("jack").contentEditable = true;
          document.getElementById("john").contentEditable = true;
          document.getElementById("joe").contentEditable = true;

          function myFunction()  {
            var jack2 = document.getElementById("jack").innerText;
            var john2 = document.getElementById("john").innerText;
            var joe2 = document.getElementById("joe").innerText;

            var total2 = parseInt(jack2) + parseInt(john2) + parseInt (joe2);

            document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total2;
          }

            myFunction();
        </script>

    
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.row:after {
clear: both;
content: "";
display: table;
```

}

"clear:both" is the problem. Either remove it or make it as "clear:right"